# Почему mysql installer for windows 64 превышает 300 мб

Tags: mysql

Раньше не устанавливал mysql вручную, а теперь полностью сам настроить сервер на локальном хосте и скачивая mysql 5.6 меня поразило что установщик весит больше 300 мб. Почему так много? может я что-то не то скачиваю вот ссылка на офф. сайт откуда скачал http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=457534
Полностью скачанный архив вести 346 мб.

Comment: я думаю, ровно по тому же, почему и «640 килобайт памяти **не** хватит всем»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я просто скачал и открыл архив. Например, там есть файл  lib/debug/mysqlserver.lib, который распакованный только 376 мб весит, а в архиве - почти 100. По факту этот файл нужен только тем, кто пишет си/с++ код и хочет смотреть "глубокие стектрейсы". То есть, 99.9 % программистов оно не нужно (а юзерам и подавно). И такого там хватает. Вот и ответ - пихают все, что бы создать вид "крутости".

Comment: Мда теперь я понимаю почему денвер многие выбирают, там ведь уже удаленно все стоить только самое нужное

Comment: У вас что, винты по одному гигабайту? Да и многие выбирают не денвер, а линукс

Comment: То, что они большие, ещё не значит, что их нужно забивать бессмысленными данными.

Comment: @KoVadim, централизованная система управления пакетами, мне кажется, очень не помешала бы в операционной системе *ms/windows*. впрочем, её отсутствие, являющееся корнем затронутой проблемы, на мой взгляд, никак не оправдывает разработчиков сторонних программ, поддерживающих «родовые дефекты» операционной системы.

Comment: В 10 винде есть примитивная поддержка пакетов.

Comment: @KoVadim, надо же! огромный прогресс налицо. не прошло и четверти века…

Comment: Пруф http://blogs.technet.com/b/packagemanagement/archive/2015/04/29/introducing-packagemanagement-in-windows-10.aspx

Comment: @KoVadim, наверно, статью писали не в pr-службе корпорации: вместо радостных слов о том, какую замечательную и крутую вещь они придумали первыми в мире, идут какие-то скучные упоминания о каких-то «студенческих поделках».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin разработка винде давно уже завязана на пакеты (тот же nuget). Распространение девелоперского софта - тоже (WebPI, уже три года как mysql можно из командной строки поставить). Разработчики mysql решили выложить на сайт zip c 376 Mb lib - это проблемы разработчиков mysql.  А распространиение обычных приложений в винде пока без пакетов - но,в самом популярном дистрибитиве linux - android - распространиение сделано тоже без пакетов, тупо полными инсталляторами. Что как бы намекает на удобство пакетов для среднестатистического юзера.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну, насчёт того, как в *ms/windows* обстоят дела с разработкой последние лет десять, вам явно виднее — вы ею хотя бы пользуетесь. а такая штука как, например, cpan — вполне себе кроссплатформенная уж лет двадцать как существует. когда программисты пишут (в том числе и) для себя, а не только «на продажу», чаще всего у них выходит и быстрей и лучше.

Comment: @PashaPash по поводу *android* aka *dalvik/linux* — вот уж не ожидал от столь опытного человека такой неосведомлённости. это никак не «дистрибутив (о.с.) linux», ведь *linux* — это программа (библиотека, если угодно), но никак не операционная система. и, между прочим, *dalvik/linux* — это отличный образец «решения на продажу». что как бы подтверждает.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin так и винда - решение на продажу. для андройда значит отсутствие пакетов - ок, а для винды - "родовой дефект". двойная мораль - это нехорошо )

Comment: @PashaPash, прошу прощения, но я не говорил, что отсутствие пакетной системы в *dalvik/linux* — это что-то хорошее. наоборот, я считаю это недостатком. ровно таким же, как и у *ms/windows*.